# How to convert SharePoint Date-Only field from UTC to local time zone

Tags: rest, azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

I've created a logic-app which reads data from SharePoint online using the get-item action.

However - I have a sharepoint-column of type Date-Only, which returns obviously just the date-portion (as date-only would imply).

The problem is, that sharepoint internally uses date-time (UTC!) to store the date. So when I create an entry in sharepoint in my local time (CET!) with the date "2016-10-20" this is stored as `2016-10-19T22:00.00Z`.

So now the logic-app-action is sending a rest-call, which will return `2016-10-19`. So how am I supposed to get my original date? Even if I would treat the response as UTC and convert it to my local time (using an azure-function) I would get `2016-10-19T02:00.00` as the result instead of `2016-10-20T02:00.00`

Comment: Where is your code? How are you setting the date? Most likely you are sending a local DateTime value (DateTimeKind.Local) which the server has to change before saving. Even if SP saved local time, you'd still get the same error if the server had a different timezone from your code. Use `ToUtc` to create a value with `DateTimeKind.UTC`, or use `DateTimeOffset` to avoid any ambiguities

Comment: BTW I think SP's services use ISO8601 (equivalent to datetimeoffset)  which means the time was modified by your code, when the local `DateTime` was converted to a `2016-10-20T00:00:00+02:00` - the correct local time in ISO8601 format

Comment: I'm editing SharePoint list-items in the SharePoint-UI. This is the response I get from the logic-app-action:
    "body": {
    [... reduced for brevity ...]        
        "orderdate": "2016-10-19"
    }

Answer (score 4):

While creating or updating entries SharePoint converts (based on current `Time Zone` selected in site `Regional Settings`) and saves datetime values in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). SharePoint Online REST service returns datetime in UTC (apart from another services in Office 365, like Outlook services where it could be controlled via `Prefer: outlook.timezone` header, see for example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations) for a more details)

> Prerequisites
>
> [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library

Having said that you need to convert datetime value from REST response in order to display it in local time:

```
var orderDateString = "2016-10-19T22:00.00Z"; //relative datetime value in REST response 
var offset = 120; //CET offset
var localOrderDate = moment.utc(orderDateString).utcOffset(offset);
console.log(localOrderDate.format('LL')); //print local date part
```

---

Or you could utilize the following function which converts the specified DateTime value from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) to local time

```
var TimeZoneUtilities = {
  utcToLocalTime: function getSPCurrentTime(webUrl,value) {
    return $.ajax({
      url: webUrl + "/_api/web/RegionalSettings/TimeZone",
      method: "GET",
      headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
    }).then(function (data) {
      var offset = -(data.d.Information.Bias + data.d.Information.StandardBias + data.d.Information.DaylightBias) / 60.0;
      return moment.utc(orderDateString).utcOffset(offset).toDate();
    });
  }
};
```

This function is similar to [`SPTimeZone.LocalTimeToUTC method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sptimezone.localtimetoutc.aspx) from SharePoint API.

Usage

```
var orderDateString = "2016-10-19T22:00.00Z"; //UTC datetime value from REST response 
var orderDate = new Date(orderDateString);
TimeZoneUtilities.utcToLocalTime(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,orderDate)
.done(function(value)
{
    console.log("Server time: " + value.format("yyyy MM dd"));
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: thx for this awesome answer - but my problem was, that I configured the field in sharepoint to "date only". Interally the date is still stored as datetime, but the time-part is omitted in the response. But still the returned value is based on UTC. This makes it impossible to convert to any other timezone, if the response is missing the time-part. I now changed the sharepoint configuration to include date *and* time.

Comment: @nyn3x did you ever found a solution for date-only fields? I don't want to display the time in these fields to the user, but have the same timezone problem as you had. So the user displayed date is always the same as the UTC value which is stored in the field, which is wrong as the regional setting has a timezone with DST which is always different from UTC.

Comment: This appears to only account for the CE timezone offset, how can you account for all?